# Mapbox - markers disappear after adding info window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I am creating an app with a map for index page and a map per each item. For some reason, the marker on the item map disappears when I add an info window. On the index map, all items are still appearing and the info window is working properly but on the item map, where I used to see a zoomed map with a marker showing the location of the item, I only get a world map without any marker. The two lines triggering this seem to be the ones with Popup and HTML:

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(element)
  .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
  .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25})
  .setHTML(marker.infoWindow.content))
  .addTo(map);
```

I would be really grateful for any tips on how to solve this, have been struggling for a while!

Comment: In case someone else has a similar problem: I solved this by simply creating a separate map for single items, without the popup. Not very eloquent perhaps, but as the code for it is not so very long, I found that to be the easiest way to get rid of the issue.